# Should I call the method abstract in Java?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have a little project to implement different sorting algorithms.

I created the abstract class called `Sorter` and it's subclasses: `BubbleSort`, `QuickSort`, `CoctailSort`, `SelectionSort`.

Almost all of the subclasses have method called `swap` (to change place between two elements), besides `MergeSort`.

The question is - is it that bad not to define method `swap` abstract, because one subclass doesn't implement it or I should rework `MergeSort` code and add `swap` method to it?

Comment: You could remove the `swap` method definition from the abstract class and declare it in a separate interface, to be implemented by all your `Sort` classes save for the `MergeSort`.

Comment: If  a class extends an abstract class then the subclass must override all the abstract methods that are present in the superclass. It depends on you what kind of functionality you need.

Comment: I didn't define swap method abstract. That method defined in subclasses, but not in MergeSort

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to achieve (other than complete your homework). What kind of contract you need to enforce?

Comment: @Mark right, but you are trying to generalize its declaration. So, without any change to your concrete classes save for implementating the interface (and `@Override` annotations if you're > Java 5), you can define the method in a separate interface while still having all concrete classes extend the abstract one.

Comment: What does `swap` do? Does it take in an array `a`, 2 indices `i` and `j`, and then swap `a[i]` with `a[j]` ?

Comment: Put the `swap` method in your `Sorter` class, but as a _non-abstract_ protected method. That way all the subclasses can use it, if they need it.

Comment: Yes, it swaps a[i] with a[j]

Comment: @Mark if the function is defined the same way for every subclass, then I'd write a `SortUtility` helper class and implement `swap` as a static method.

Comment: Does your abstract class call `swap(...)` in any way or does it depend on the implementations when and where to call it? If the latter then it would probably best be placed in some utility class.

Answer (score 0):

I think this guy https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/solid-class-design-the-liskov-substitution-principle/ have the same problem you have. One solution is to make one abstract class called something like SorterThatNeedSwap* that extends your sorter class and then all classes that need swap can extend that class. In that SorterThatNeedSwap you can define abstract method swap. Classes that don't need swap method can extend Sorter directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Interface to keep swap method. And implement it where you need to override swap method. Interfaces are like 100% abstract classes all methods inside the interface are implicitly public implicitly abstract . Following link to oracle documentation about interfaces.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Answer (score 0):

Try an interface that call Swap.
All sorts except MergeSort implement this interface.